# Should using the review tools also mark something as flagged?

Tags: support, review-page

While using the review tools, I noticed something, but was unsure if by design, or a bug.

It seems that if I come across a question or answer when browsing the site, and flag it, the [flag summary](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary) seems to reflect this.

If I am using the review tools though, and mark something for deletion, it doesn't seem to flag this anymore.

I understand there is a difference between flagging and deleting, but at least on how it is implemented currently in the site, it appears to be rather confusing. Almost like two very similar but different, overlapping features.

Answer (score 4):

No - this is by design. (And you are correct it is a subtle point between how flagging works differently within and without the review UI).

The review tool is intended to get people to close things naturally. Flags are for severe issues where the site is actively being harmed and not just for routine cleaning.

Of course, when the site is new, you can't really close questions or reopen them due to a lack of trusted users.

We are getting to the point where the community is closing the worst questions by normal vote and not needing a binding vote from a diamond moderator.

Hooray for community moderation! Thanks to all who are reviewing.